# Validate input type number html

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

See http://jsbin.com/oqujuf/1/edit

```
$('input').keyup -> console.log @value
```

Prints empty when I write a letter in input, how can I delete letters as they are type inside input, I was trying this:

```
@value = @value.replace(/\D/, '')
```

But is does not work because as soon as I write letter there value returns empty.

## Update

I used this way:

```
if !@value then @value = ''
```

This works. But my question is now this, I want validation to remove just letters how could I do that?

There is another problem: let's say I use a range from 5 to 50, if I want to write 15, as soon as I write 1 value disappear, how would you solve these 2 issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve the problem, if I understand it correctly, would be to restrict the characters in the field by rejecting any keycodes not matching numerics and a few other keys like delete, tab and arrow keys, like so:

```
$ ->
  $('input').keypress (e)->
    acceptedKeys = ([8,9].concat [48..57]).concat [46]
    unless (e.which in acceptedKeys)
      return false
```

Notice the use of the `keypress` event instead of `keyup`. You might want to also include the `.` character keycode (46) if you want to accept decimals. A downside of this approach is that it would also prevent pasting values into the field with a keyboard shortcut but *would* allow a paste of any characters using the context menu with the mouse.

jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/idukin/7/edit

Comment: I am having this in console, I think is jsbin problem: Processor is not ready yet - trying again

Comment: Seems like in jsbin, when you get this error, you can just click the "Run with JS" button in the output window to run the script and all is well.

Comment: Is working, but allows to enter this chars `\`ç´ñ`, maybe others more

Comment: Ah, with keypress, the keyCodes for arrow keys seem to map to other chars, and it isn't necessary to explicitly allow them anyway. I edited the answer above as well as the jsbin link. Try it now.

Comment: Interesting... doesn't allow those characters for me. What browser are you using?